# Absolutely positioned anchors are too tall on mobile

Tags: html, hyperlink, responsive-design, mobile-website

I'm experimenting around with my homepage at https://stephenvk.xyz (It's deliberately kinda cheesy, though suggestions for things like a better background are welcome) and I had the idea to make my navigation bar a clipart of a computer memory module. I used a tool at https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/ to generate anchors that will scale with the image, but when viewing my homepage on mobile they're too tall. This does not occur on any other page despite the code being exactly the same. It may be worth noting that I experienced a similar error on PC when I tried embedding a YouTube video via [Invidious](http://invidious.site/), though a normal YouTube embed was fine (I wound up just using a normal YT embed because Invidious wouldn't play it at a higher resolution than 144p).

Here's my CSS:

```
.sidebar {position: relative; float: left; width: 10%;}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar"><img src="/gfx/memory.gif" width=100%>
<a href="https://stephenvk.xyz/" title="Home" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 4.28%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.54%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="/murica" title="Murica" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 14.87%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.54%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="/linuxboss" title="Linux Boss" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 25.46%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.43%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="/about" title="About Me" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 36.05%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.54%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="/links" title="Links" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 57.03%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.54%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" title="" style="position: absolute; left: 7.47%; top: 67.62%; width: 66.39%; height: 7.54%; z-index: 2;"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that trying to set the size and absolute position of all these anchors is going to give you grief and it will always feel like a struggle to make everything work responsively.

Have you considered splitting up the image of the memory chip into smaller images that match ths size of your anchors? And then wrapping your links around these small images?

If you approached it this way, everything will scale nicely.